# GWT ScriptInjector VS adding script tag to index.html page

Tags: javascript, gwt, javascript-injection

Why use `ScriptInjector` class.

What is the difference between using `ScriptInjector` to inject a js file and adding the link with a `<script>` tag directly to the `index.html` file.
Is there any advantage of using the `ScriptInjector` over adding the script tag in the `index.html` file.

One thing that comes to my mind is that the initial load may be a lot more if you add a ton of scripts in the `index.html` file using `<script>` which are not going to be used until later. `ScriptInjector` will cut down on the initial load by loading the script asynchronously only when required.

Answer (score 5):

The main advantage of using `ScriptInjector` is that you can leverage the Java language to inject JS files (or JS code) in your page. In the context of a GWT application, this is cleaner than using JSNI.

You're right, adding the `<script>` tags up front in the HTML file might lead to performance issues.

Answer (score 3):

Advantages of Using ScriptInjector are

- ScriptInjector Dynamically create script tag and attach it to DOM meaning based on the condition you can inject script(js).
- If we include lot of Script tag on host page, which will take lot of time to load the script tag(also it will block untill its get executed).

Answer (score 2):

You already described one of the key advantages.

Another advantage is that some scripts may never be used. For example, you may have a script that integrates Google Wallet payments or Facebook login, but not every user needs these features every time. So there is no reason to load these scripts until actually needed.